# How to restrict creating tasks in opportunities

Tags: apex, community, opportunity, account, tasks

Hi friends i got stuck in a problem.

I gave view all access to all opportunities & accounts to my sales reps.

But i want to restrict sales reps to  create tasks only when they are try to create in other opportunity owner or account owners

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: I try to create a validation rule in tasks but it didn't work for me...@itzmukeshy7

Comment: what is the rule code?

Comment: You will need a before insert trigger on activity BC validation rule on task can't get to opp owner ID.

Answer (score 1):

While validation rules would seem to be the way to go, there is no polymorphic syntax to go from the Task's `whatId` to the parent object. So, a trigger is called for.

```
trigger TaskEntryCheck on Task (before insert) {

   set<ID> searchAidSet = new set<ID> ();
   set<ID> searchOidSet = new set<ID> ();
   for (Task t : Trigger.new) { // collect relevant whatIds for bulkifed soql
     if (t.whatId.getSobjectType() == Account.SobjectType)
         searchAIdSet.add(t.whatId);
     if (t.whatId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SobjectType)
         searchOIdSet.add(t.whatId);
   }
   map<ID,Account> aIdToAccountMap = new map<ID,Account> (
               [select id, ownerId from Account where ID IN :searchAidSet]);
   map<ID,Opportunity> oIdToOppoMap = new map<ID,Opportunity> (
               [select id, ownerId from Opportunity where ID IN :searchOidSet]);

   // now, go thru Tasks and see if they are for accounts or oppos
   // and if so, see if the parent ownerId is same as running User
   for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
       if (aIdToAccountMap.containsKey(t.whatId) &&
           aIdToAccountMap.get(t.whatId).ownerId != UserInfo.getUserId())
           t.addError('You can only add tasks to Accounts you own');
       if (oIdToOppoMap.containsKey(t.whatId) &&
           oIdToOppoMap.get(t.whatId).ownerId != UserInfo.getUserId())
           t.addError('You can only add tasks to Oppos you own');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add one more condition here that logged in or running user is not admin if this makes sense in this context.